# Different animations for different scenes for a linked armature

Tags: linked-data, proxies

I have a simple scene containing an object that is parented to an armature.
I made a copy out of the scene by choosing the "link objects" option, because I want to be able to edit one scene and have the change automatically reflect in the other scene.

The problem is figuring out a way of giving the same armature different animations in each scene.  If I animate the armature in scene 1, scene 2 will automatically have the same animation. I tried to link a different action to the armature in the action editor, but the action changes in both scenes.

Is there a way for me to link an object from a scene while still animating it individually? Proxies don't seem to work if I'm simply linking from another scene in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you link an Object from one Scene to another all changes are transferred from one Scene to another, even animations. That is because the same Object and Armature are used. There is a quick way of fixing this for your case: Add a new armature object in each scene, then select each one of them and make sure they use the same Armature. You can make the selection here:
[image]

All changes to the Armature in Edit Mode will be transferred to all other scenes but changes made in the Pose Mode will be Scene specific.

Comment: Wow, that actually sounds like a really great solution! I will test it extensively tomorrow!

Comment: Damn, I tried this and ran into a problem: Everything you described works great until this step: how do I parent the mesh to this new armature in Scene 2, without also automatically parenting the mesh in Scene 1 to the same armature?

Comment: Hi! I did some more testing and got past the first problem by creating also a new mesh object to which I linked the original mesh in the object data tab. Now the only issue is the shape keys: is there a way animate also them separately in both scenes?

Comment: This is a known limitation of current Blender versions, no way around it except making all objects unique, as far as I know. This is being worked on for future versions of Blender.